# usar selectedValue de DropDownList

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

Trabajo con ASP.NET Core 1.1 Visual Studio 2017 – EntityFramework 1.0.0 , Microsoft .Net Framework 4.7.02046, SQL Server 2012 LocalDB C#
Estoy haciendo mi primera experiencia con dichas herramientas. Sigo el ejemplo ContosoUniversity desarrollado en la documentación de MS.
He leído y probado muchas consultas sin encontrar la solución al siguiente problema:
Quiero recuperar y utilizar el selectedValue de un DropDownList.

Model

```
    public class Rol
{
    public int RolID { get; set; }
    public string EnRol { get; set; }
 …


}
```

Controller

```
var rolQuery = from r in _context.Roles
                           orderby r.RolID
                           select r;
var ListaDesplegableRoles = new SelectList(rolQuery.AsNoTracking(),
                "RolID",
                "EnRol",
                elegidoRol);
ViewBag.RolId = ListaDesplegableRoles;
```

View

```
div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">En rol de:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select name="eR" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RolId"  >
                <option value="">-elegir rol--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

Hasta aquí funciona perfecto.

Cuando paso el DropDownList desde el Model, no tengo problemas. En este caso que lo paso por ViewBag no encuentro la forma de recuperar el selectedvalue para usarlo en otra action (Post).

También desearía conocer qué documentación o libro leer (tengo varios descargados de MS docs y también un libro sobre C#)
Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo tu problema. Quieres enviar el valor del select a otro action?

Comment: Entiendo que hay dos posibilidades.      1.  Una es la que señalaste.    2. Poder utilizarlo en la view, lo que me permitiría también enviarlo a una action o mostrarlo en la misma página.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien tu quieres que al recuperar la lista se coloque en el sitio donde se selecciono bueno si es eso la forma es usar un dropdowlistfor

en el controller

```
List<producto> ListaTab = await _iPro.ListarPorFamilia(1);
                    ViewBag.ListaTabl = new SelectList(ListaTab, "productoID", "productoname");
```

en la vista

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="productoID" class="control-label"></label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.productoID, ViewBag.ListaTabl as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        <span asp-validation-for="productoID" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

eso pone el list en en valor que trae productoID.

pero si no es eso bueno explicame un poco mas y talvez puedo ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Maria el problema es que tu select funciona bien a la hora de mostrarse pero cuando pasas los parámetros a una acción de tipo post no llega el rol porque has definido `name="eR"` y tu metodo puede que espere un RolID. Prueba cambiando el nombre del parámetro que recoges en el select.

```
<select name="RolID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RolId"  >
            <option value="">-elegir rol--</option></select>
```

Tambien te recomiendo esta via para recoger la lista en tu controlador que está mejor optimizada.

```
ViewData["RolId"] = new SelectList(_context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.RolID), "RolID", "EnRol");
```

Comment: Hice ambos cambios y funcionó como antes: se ve bien DropDownList pero no sé como referenciar el selectedValue.
Quiero intentar algo como esto:
    var elegido = RolId.selectedvalue;

Comment: A ver si entiendo. Lo que quieres es que salga un rol seleccionado por defecto al mostrar el DropDownList?

Comment: No, no, eso lo puedo hacer. Lo que quiero es poder usar el rol elegido por el usuario para hacer un alta en la base de datos.

Comment: Para recogerlo en el controlador debes pasar como parámetro lo que envias desde la vista, en este caso  (int RolID) que es el name de tu select

Comment: Para simplificar hice lo siguiente: Abrir el View **Edit** de l controller **Rols** con el siguiente código:   <div>
        <a 
           asp-controller="Rols"
           asp-action="Edit"
           asp-route-id="9">volver</a>
    </div>  
Es decir le puse el valor de un RolID que existe y funcionó bien.

Comment: Pero necesito en el lugar de ese **"9"** poner el selectedvalue.
Hice los intentos fallidos:   **asp-route-id="RolID"**   tamben **arrobaRolID**,   **arrobaViewModel.RolID**   pero todos dieron error.